# c# Code behind access from asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am having a trouble with very much likely simple problem. Could someone please take a look and tell me what I am missing?

I am trying to call a code-behind procedure from asp.net page, however, the procedure is somehow not even run - i have placed a breakpoint for debug and it seems i just bypass the calling somehow.

I use very simple nonsense code just to ilustrate the problem:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MP_front_header.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="seznam_spolecnosti.aspx.cs" Inherits="SWMv01.WebFormC" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# SWMv01.WebFormC.TestMe() %>' ></asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using SWMv01.App_Classes;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Threading;

namespace SWMv01
{
    public partial class WebFormC : BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public static string TestMe()
        {
            int tst;
            string tststr;
            tst = 1 + 1;
            tststr = Convert.ToString(tst);

            return tststr;
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks to anyone who wastes his/her time helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binding syntax and will only work if you call DataBind(). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.71).aspx.

Comment: Stupid me, sorry for the lame question. The problem is, in my code I am actually using list view and i am trying to bind the template similar way and databind is used in code-behind. I will focus on the binding though. Thank you for your time.